# Which version of safeMath to import from openZeppelin contracts on github.com?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

There are more than one version of `safeMath` on `openZeppelin`. On `master` branch, the URL is:

```
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol
```

Besides `master` branch, there are quite a few other version available. Here is version 3.0.0:

```
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v3.0.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol
```

If someone wants to use the `safeMath` in her/his smart contact development, which version shall be imported? Shall import `master` branch at any time?

`master` branch:

```
    pragma "^0.7.0"
    import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol"

    contract myContract() {
     //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the solidity version you are using in your main contract. For contract using versions >=0.8.0 the use of safeMath read [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/101584).
For contract written in older version (say) 0.6.0 the use of the latest safeMath library written for version 0.8.0 will not be compatible.
In conclusion, try using the version of safeMath that is the same with the version of your main contract.